# Freehub body fell off. Now it's back on, but big freewheel drag

Tags: cassette, hub

**Update: I managed to slide the freehub + cassette back onto the hub - took a bit of persuasion, but easy once I had the technique. But the freehub now has a significant drag - when I rotate the pedals forward, the back wheel spin stops within a couple of seconds. Any ideas on how to diagnose?**

New bike that I've been riding for a couple of weeks without incident. I took the rear wheel off as part of a deep clean. As I removed the thru-axle and took off the wheel, the freehub body (DT Swiss 240) and cassette simply came off together.

The cassette lockring is still as tight as normal, and I can't see any missing springs or other parts. There is a loose part inside the lockring - I think this is the end cap. When I try to place the freehub body + cassette back on to the hub, it slides on about 0.5 cm and then won't move any further - nothing obvious blocking it. I've tried turning it anti-clockwise while sliding it on, but that doesn't help.

Is there a straightforward way to put the body + cassette back on the hub? Or do I need to wait until I can visit the LBS on Monday?

[image]

Comment: About your update, with a Mavic hub, that could happen if the axle is over tightened.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have experience DT Swiss rear hubs, but with Mavic ones, that have a similar design. The ratchet mechanism is designed to be serviced without specific tools, as a result the cassette+freehub body can be removed quite easily (intentionally or not). And they can be reassembled without tools as well. The cassette is locked when the wheel is on the bike. So, I'd think it's a feature, not a bug.

You can reassemble it yourself, just check with the manual/exploded view to be sure that all parts are there and in the right order/orientation.

This video may be interesting for you:

Comment: Many thanks - I'm looking at this video now.

Comment: I'm thinking possibly a spring has been put out of kilter, hopefully no permanent deformation, but possible.